# Is jumping over/removing `PHDR` program header in ELF file for executable OK? If so, why?

Tags: c++, c, elf, readelf

I was doing some hacking in the binary for this simple C++ program to understand program headers for ELF:

```
int main(){ }
```

compiled with:

```
❯ make
g++ -O0 -fverbose-asm -no-pie -o main main.cpp
```

I used `readelf -l main` to get the following:

```
Elf file type is EXEC (Executable file)
Entry point 0x401020
There are 11 program headers, starting at offset 64

Program Headers:
  Type           Offset             VirtAddr           PhysAddr
                 FileSiz            MemSiz              Flags  Align
  PHDR           0x0000000000000040 0x0000000000400040 0x0000000000400040
                 0x0000000000000268 0x0000000000000268  R      0x8
  INTERP         0x00000000000002a8 0x00000000004002a8 0x00000000004002a8
                 0x000000000000001c 0x000000000000001c  R      0x1
      [Requesting program interpreter: /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2]
  LOAD           0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000400000 0x0000000000400000
                 0x00000000000004c0 0x00000000000004c0  R      0x1000
...
```

I see in this documentation: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/elf.5.html for PHDR:

> The array element, if present, specifies the loca‐
>                           tion and size of the program header table itself,
>                           both in the file and in the memory image of the pro‐
>                           gram.  This segment type may not occur more than
>                           once in a file.  Moreover, it may occur only if the
>                           program header table is part of the memory image of
>                           the program.  If it is present, it must precede any
>                           loadable segment entry.

**The presence of `if present` in the quote made me wonder what would happen if I just jumped over the PHDR header.** I used vim's hex editor to change the binary layout of `main` using `:%!xxd` (be sure to run `:%!xxd -r` before saving, or else it's not a binary file anymore) to get from:

```
00000000: 7f45 4c46 0201 0100 0000 0000 0000 0000  .ELF............
00000010: 0200 3e00 0100 0000 2010 4000 0000 0000  ..>..... .@.....
00000020: 4000 0000 0000 0000 1839 0000 0000 0000  @........9......
```

to:

```
00000000: 7f45 4c46 0201 0100 0000 0000 0000 0000  .ELF............
00000010: 0200 3e00 0100 0000 2010 4000 0000 0000  ..>..... .@.....
00000020: 7800 0000 0000 0000 1839 0000 0000 0000  @........9......
```

(Only changing the 20th byte), to jump over the length of the PHDR header. I run `readelf` again to verify it's still a valid ELF file:

```
❯ readelf -l main

Elf file type is EXEC (Executable file)
Entry point 0x401020
There are 11 program headers, starting at offset 120

Program Headers:
  Type           Offset             VirtAddr           PhysAddr
                 FileSiz            MemSiz              Flags  Align
  INTERP         0x00000000000002a8 0x00000000004002a8 0x00000000004002a8
                 0x000000000000001c 0x000000000000001c  R      0x1
      [Requesting program interpreter: /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2]
  ...
```

**And surprisingly the program still executes perfectly fine. Why do we even need the PHDR header? Is it useful for linking and/or other situations? It seems like it's not used during runtime at all so why do we have this lying around?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the main program is of type `ET_EXEC` (non-PIE), it's probably runnable without `PT_PHDR`. The main use of `PT_PHDR` is being able to compare the (unrelocated) address in the header with the actual runtime address of the program headers (obtained by the dynamic linker via `AT_PHDR` in the aux vector) to determine the offset at which the PIE executable was loaded.

I'm not sure what glibc's dynamic linker's requirements for having `PT_PHDR` are, but in musl libc's we only need it for computing this load offset, and otherwise it's not used at all.

Comment: I see. In the specifications in the man page, it says "if present". What would happen if in musl libc could not detect a PHDR header?

Comment: For ET_EXEC (non-PIE), it'd just run normally. For PIE it'd fail to relocate properly and likely crash during relocation processing.

Answer (score 4):

> I run readelf again to verify it's still a valid ELF file:

Note that although valid ELF, it now has corrupted 11th entry in the in the program header table (since you didn't decrement the count of program headers).

> And surprisingly the program still executes perfectly fine.

This program doesn't use *any* features of the dynamic linker, so the fact that you've corrupted its structures doesn't manifest itself.

Now try to call some routines from `libc.so.6`, or call `dlopen` and `dlsym`, and see if that still works.

Looking at the GLIBC loader source ([rtld.c](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=elf/rtld.c)), it does care very much about `PT_PHDR`, so I would be surprised if things still work without it.

Comment: I see. Great answer! Thanks for linking the loader source code here. I see that it's being used here: https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=elf/rtld.c#l1414 in `dl_main`. Without the context of what `phdr` is passed in to `dl_main`, I'm a bit confused on why `main_map`'s load address is deduced by *subtracting* the virtual address (in the example posted in question it's `0x400040`). Wouldn't we want to *add* the virtual address to the current address so we can load the .so there?

Comment: @OneRaynyDay Please ask a new question, since this doesn't have anything to do with the original question, and since questions are free ;-)

Comment: Sure :) I'll ask one.